# Problem to make a procedure with an update

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

When I try to create a stored procedure in Oracle what I need is to update a table with the id1 that is the one that inserts a user, the other id2 and id3 are for the same function but I can not do it with one, I use an update for that, then I use the case because it has to be random then I create a variable that assigns a number from 1 to 3 and according to that I choose the Case to be executed

The code I am trying to make is this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE AERO_COR(ID1 IN INT, ID2 IN INT, ID3 IN INT) IS
  ID         INT;
  NOMBRE     VARCHAR2(50);
  ID_PA      INT;
  ID_PR      INT;
  CONTADOROP INT;
  CURSOR CURSOR_AEROPUERTO IS
    SELECT * FROM TABLE(AEROPUERTO);
  FILA_CURSOR CURSOR_AEROPUERTO%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  OPEN CURSOR_AEROPUERTO;
  CONTADOROP := ROUND(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(1, 3));
  LOOP
    FETCH CURSOR_AEROPUERTO
      INTO FILA_CURSOR;
    EXIT WHEN CURSOR_AEROPUERTO%NOTFOUND;
  
    UPDATE AEROPUERTO
       SET AEROPUERTO.ID_PRINCIPAL = CASE  WHEN CONTADOROP = '1' THEN ID1
     WHERE AEROPUERTO.ID BETWEEN 1 AND 7,  WHEN CONTADOROP = '2' THEN ID1
     WHERE AEROPUERTO.ID BETWEEN 7 AND 14, WHEN CONTADOROP = '3' THEN ID1
     WHERE AEROPUERTO.ID BETWEEN 14 AND 20,
    --ELSE 3 WHERE AEROPUERTO.ID BETWEEN 14 AND 20
     WHERE AEROPUERTO.ID != NULL;
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE CURSOR_AEROPUERTO;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

i have seen the query today already i think and even then i didn't get the logic.

I told you alredy that your query doesn't makes sense als case WHen has no where

but you can ann the condition to the when and you need an and as i have shown you in the link in the comment earlier

So use this, amd see if it works.

it is usually tried to make mutually excluding conditions, so i added also an ELSE because what will you do  if AEROPUERTO.ID is 15 but CONTADOROP  is '2'

So i think you need to chekc th logic again.

```
UPDATE AEROPUERTO SET AEROPUERTO.ID_PRINCIPAL =
    CASE
        WHEN CONTADOROP = '1' AND AEROPUERTO.ID BETWEEN 1 AND 7 THEN
            ID1 
        WHEN CONTADOROP = '2' AND AEROPUERTO.ID BETWEEN 7 AND 14 THEN
            ID1 
        WHEN CONTADOROP = '3' AND AEROPUERTO.ID BETWEEN 14 AND 20 THEN
            ID1 
        ELSE -1  --maybe you need also one of the, because the condotions are not exclusive
     END 
        --ELSE 3 WHERE AEROPUERTO.ID BETWEEN 14 AND 20
WHERE AEROPUERTO.ID != NULL;
```